# How can i get older version of ppa?

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa

Is there a way for me to get older version of a ppa? I have searched on google but to no avail. The reason I asked this because newer version of the ppa only supports higher version ubuntu and I have used that ppa before and confirmed that it worked well.

I am using travis CI to build my sources which I use the ppa for, so I lost access to the working machine after the source has been built

This question is different from [Getting older packages from ppa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231074/getting-older-packages-from-ppa). I need the older version of the whole ppa not just specific package.

Thank you