# How to install older (downgrade) package from PPA?

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, maas

I currently have MAAS 1.9.4 installed. For multiple reasons I want to install (and try) version 1.9.3. When I issue the command `sudo apt-cache policy maas`, I can only select 1.9.4 and 1.5(.4). I know that the PPA for MAAS is coming from launchpad. So I looked there if I could download the older package without any luck so far.

I have looked at [1] and the answer kind of suggests that only the latest version of a PPA can be downloaded (correct me if I am wrong). If that is the case, is there any alternative road I can take to still install version 1.9.3?

Question: How can I install an older version of a package?

[1] [Getting older packages from ppa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231074/getting-older-packages-from-ppa)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting older packages from ppa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231074/getting-older-packages-from-ppa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a new version of a package is uploaded to a repository, the previous one is deleted, so it is no longer possible to obtain it (from that repository). You can see the available packages on the MAAS repository [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/maas/stable/ubuntu/pool/main/m/maas/), and notice that there are no 1.9.3 packages.

If I were in your situation, I would probably contact the repository maintainers to ask them if they can give you the 1.9.3 package.

Comment: very sad IMHO, but is there maybe some sort of archive I can look up old packages? something like google cache. Its a wild thought, but you never know.